# How do I retrieve a contact through the native phone book?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I would like to know if there is a package on flutter to allow me to retrieve a contact from the phone's native directory (I would like to do a contact import feature to create a client in my app). I've tested a lot of packages, but for example packages like *contact_picker* or *easy_contact_picker* works perfectly on iOS, but crashes on Android... Do you have any idea how I can do that?

an example of the crash I have on Android :

```
D/EGL_emulation(18178): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1bde460: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1b955c0)
D/FlutterView(18178): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@11b78c1
D/AndroidRuntime(18178): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(18178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18178): Process: fr.myproject.myproject, PID: 18178
E/AndroidRuntime(18178): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2015, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3776i4b14e6d913284bbe/1 flg=0x1 }} to activity {fr.myproject.myproject/com.example.myproject_mobile.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.app.Activity.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.app.Activity.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.appleeducate.flutter.contactpicker.ContactPickerPlugin.onActivityResult(ContactPickerPlugin.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:634)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:367)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:546)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:594)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    ... 11 more
I/Process (18178): Sending signal. PID: 18178 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: did you try this [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't give access to the native view of the contacts directory, it's up to me to recreate a view :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the contack_picker plugin, but through a fork git (see https://github.com/danysz/contact_picker). It is also necessary to **go on the flutter beta channel**, because in stable it doesn't work (certainly a regression at this level).